# USB Headset Output Suddenly Stopped

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, headset

I have been using my USB Headset with no problems up to about a week ago.

Ubuntu registers that the device is plugged in and I can select it in the sound menu for output or in PulseAudio Volume control, However I hear nothing.

I have messed with just about every setting going, in the sound menu and the PAV Contol menus to no avail.

The headset is not the problem as it works fine in windows.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this?

(As a side note, the Mic works fine)

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Also, what version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: I would love to provide, however the problem went away after a fresh install. Something I was meaning to do anyway, not because of the sound issues. You can't close questions right?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved with a fresh install

> I would love to provide, however the problem went away after a fresh install. Something I was meaning to do anyway, not because of the sound issues. You can't close questions right?